# why the html content not shown out when running

Tags: html, vue.js

Now i use visual studio code to do my project. I can build my code without error, but when running, it no show out the content for html file, only have show css like header abd footer. i have click button on header but cannot go to other page.Here is the sample code

code in index.html

```
<nav>
        <a href="#/home">List</a>
        <a href="#/insert">New student</a>
        <a href="#/feedback">Student feedback</a>
    </nav>
```

Vue router

```
const router = new VueRouter({
            routes: [
                { path: '/home', component: load('home') },
                { path: '/insert', component: load('insert') },
                { path: '/update/:id', component: load('update') },
                { path: '/feedback', component: load('feedback') },
                { path: '*', redirect: '/home' }
            ]
        });
```

File name and type: _home.html, _insert.html, _update.html, _feedback.html

Can help me see the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should edit directly to index.html as Vue is Single Page Application (SPA) framework. Instead, you should use Vue Component for each page.

This video might help you to figure out how to use Vue and Vue Router properly: https://youtu.be/nnVVOe7qdeQ

## Edit:

For sake of clarity, Let me build simplified diagram of Vue project for you.

[image: Simplified Vue Project Diagram]

First of all, make sure you create the project via [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/). It guides you to build your new vue project better.

Let's say we have 3 pages:

- Home
- About
- Another

Each page has its own CSS, HTML (we call it template), and JavaScript in one file, the `.vue` file. To connect them, we need a first entrance, `main.js`. Inside of it, we can configure the router.

### Inside `main.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import HomePage from "./HomePage.vue";
import AboutPage from "./AboutPage.vue";
import AnotherPage from "./AnotherPage.vue";

// This is your router configuration
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
  [
    { path: "/",        component: HomePage },
    { path: "/about",   component: AboutPage },
    { path: "/another", component: AnotherPage },
  ],
  mode: "history",
});

// Initialize Vue App
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Then, we need to create `App.vue` and put `<router-view />` inside of it.

### Inside `App.vue` source file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // Keep this empty. Except if you
  // need to add sidebar or any else.
}
</script>
```

### Now you're ready to create those three pages

Every pages looks like this:

```
<style scoped>
  // Your CSS here
</style>

<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Your HTML here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Your reactive data here
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // Your script here
    },
    methods: {
      // Your functions here
    },
  }
</script>
```

That's all I can explain, hope it helps. If I missed something, please don't hesitate to tell me. Thank you!

Comment: i think is can because vue can support multiple page application. My problem is i cannot link all the pages

Comment: My code similar like your code to solve it and it works but i no use import method.